# Extract rows from matrix in individual vectors without a for loop

Tags: matlab, vector, matrix

```
A = [1 2 3 4 5; 6 7 8 9 10; 11 12 13 14 15];
```

The first row contains x, the second y and the third row z-data of a number of points which I'd like to plot using `scatter 3`. This function takes vectors of x, y and z data as input arguments. I'd like to have a simple way to extract the rows of my matrix `A` so I can store them in individual vectors, which then can serve as inputs to `scatter3`?

currently I have this:

```
vec_x = A(1,:);
vec_y = A(2,:);
vec_z = A(3,:);

scatter3(vec_x, vec_y, vec_z);
```

Is there a nicer way, which combines the first three statements in one in the following way:

```
[vec_x, vec_y, vec_z] = A(.....);
```

Comment: What about scatter3(A(1,:), A(2,:), A(3,:)); ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use

```
>> [X,Y,Z] = deal(A(1,:), A(2,:), A(3,:));
>> scatter3(X,Y,Z);
```

But, as mentioned by rcompton, a simple

```
>> scatter3(A(1,:), A(2,:), A(3,:));
```

would then be shorter...

Comment: hm...seems reasonable